# Working with dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been collecting Twitter data for a couple of days now and, among other things, I need to analyze how content propagates. I created a list of timestamps when users were interested in content and imported twitter timestamps in pandas df with the column name 'timestamps'. It looks like this:

```
0     Sat Dec 14 05:13:28 +0000 2013
1     Sat Dec 14 05:21:12 +0000 2013
2     Sat Dec 14 05:23:10 +0000 2013
3     Sat Dec 14 05:27:54 +0000 2013
4     Sat Dec 14 05:37:43 +0000 2013
5     Sat Dec 14 05:39:38 +0000 2013
6     Sat Dec 14 05:41:39 +0000 2013
7     Sat Dec 14 05:43:46 +0000 2013
8     Sat Dec 14 05:44:50 +0000 2013
9     Sat Dec 14 05:47:33 +0000 2013
10    Sat Dec 14 05:49:29 +0000 2013
11    Sat Dec 14 05:55:03 +0000 2013
12    Sat Dec 14 05:59:09 +0000 2013
13    Sat Dec 14 05:59:45 +0000 2013
14    Sat Dec 14 06:17:19 +0000 2013
```

etc. What I want to do is to sample every 10min and count how many users are interested in content in each time frame. My problem is that I have no clue how to process the timestamps I imported from Twitter. Should I use regular expressions or is there any better approach to this? I would appreciate if someone could provide some pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's ISO date format, it can be easily converted to datetime with `pd.to_datetime`:

```
>>> df[:2]
                        timestamp
0  Sat Dec 14 05:13:28 +0000 2013
1  Sat Dec 14 05:21:12 +0000 2013

>>> df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
>>> df[:2]
              timestamp
0   2013-12-14 05:13:28
1   2013-12-14 05:21:12
```

To resample, you can make it an index, and use [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling)

```
>>> df.index = df['timestamp']
>>> df.resample('20Min', 'count')
2013-12-14 05:00:00  timestamp    1
2013-12-14 05:20:00  timestamp    5
2013-12-14 05:40:00  timestamp    8
2013-12-14 06:00:00  timestamp    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question. How do I sample this df? I need to see how many users request content in 10min intervals (or whichever interval). How do I find all elements that are in interval from 5:13:28 until 5:23:28? (if you could point me to any tutorial or documentation). I have never worked with time in pandas.

Comment: @Anastasia there is builtin resample method, see example and link to docs in my answer.